# What can I polymorph into, whose natural attacks count as magic for DR?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, polymorph, damage-reduction

Are there any monsters you can polymorph into that allow you to attack as if you had a magical weapon for the purposes of Damage Reduction?

I think an example would be easier to understand: 
If I meet a gargoyle then use metamorphosis to turn into a gargoyle, will my claw (1d4+2) attacks damage the gargoyle (Damage reduction 10/magic)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The natural weapons of a creature possessing DR X/magic bypass DR X/magic, but many polymorph effects can't grant DR...

According to the [*Monster Manual* errata](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111205827/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata) the special ability DR X/magic is a supernatural ability, and supernatural abilities aren't gained upon using the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*polymorph*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/polymorph.htm) [trans] (*PH* 263) *et al.* The *Monster Manual* on [Damage Reduction](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#damageReduction) says that

> Some monsters are vulnerable to magic weapons. Any weapon with at least a +1 magical enhancement bonus on attack and damage rolls overcomes the damage reduction of these monsters. **Such creatures’ natural weapons (but not their attacks with weapons) are treated as magic weapons for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction.** For example, the gargoyle has damage reduction 10/magic and can strike as a magic weapon for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction. (307)

Emphasis mine. (And, yes, really, the [gargoyle](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/gargoyle.htm) is the actual example.) This typically means a creature's ability to bypass DR X/magic is contingent upon the creature first *having* DR X/magic, which, as I said, the spell *polymorph* doesn't provide. (Note that a specific creature's ability to bypass DR X/magic *can* override this general rule, but see below.)

### ...Although there are ways around this...

The 9th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*shapechange*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shapechange.htm) [trans] (*PH* 277-8) or the feat Assume Supernatural Ability (*Savage Species* 30-1) can grant a user one or more of a creature's supernatural abilities, including damage reduction.

(I'm not a psionics guy, but the powers [*metamorphosis*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/metamorphosis.htm) and [*greater metamorphosis*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/metamorphosisGreater.htm) seem similar enough to *polymorph* and *shapechange*, respectively, that similar rules apply. A contributor with more expertise in that arena can address whether there's a psionics trick that makes assuming a supernatural ability available earlier or more easily than the feat [Metamorphic Transfer](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicFeats.htm#metamorphicTransfer) (*XPH* 48).)

#### ...And there are *a lot* of monsters

It wouldn't surprise me if there were a creature that possesses as an extraordinary natural attack the ability to bypass DR X/magic with its natural weapons. A creature that possesses such an ability would grant it to a caster who used *polymorph* to assume that creature's form. However, I am unaware of a creature that *has* such a specific extraordinary special attack.